# error deleting item from list after passing through function

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, linked-list, iterator

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what's happening when I try to delete an element from a list in this program i'm working on.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int findHigherSkillLevel(int skillLevel, list<int>::iterator *it, list<int> &list) {
  if (it == NULL) return 0;

  if (**it == (skillLevel + 1)) {
    it = list.erase(it);    
    return 1 + findHigherSkillLevel(**it, it, list) + findHigherSkillLevel(**it, --it, list);
  }

  return 0;
}

int findLowerSkillLevel(int skillLevel, list<int>::iterator *it, list<int> &list) {
  if (it == NULL) return 0;

  if (**it == (skillLevel - 1)) {
    it = list.erase(it);
    return 1 + findLowerSkillLevel(**it, it, list) + findLowerSkillLevel(**it, --it, list);
  }

  return 0;
}

int findGroupsSizes(int skillLevel, list<int>::iterator *it, list<int> &list) {
  if (it == NULL) return 0;

  int groupSize = 1;
  it = list.erase(it);
  groupSize += findHigherSkillLevel(**it, it, list) + findLowerSkillLevel(**it, it, list);

  return groupSize;
}

int main() {
  int t; // the number of test cases
  cin >> t;
  vector<list<int> > skillLevels(t, list<int>());
  // input for each test case
  for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    int n; // number of students for this test case
    cin >> n;

    // initialize the list for this test case
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
       int skillLevel;
       cin >> skillLevel;
       skillLevels[i].push_back(skillLevel);
    }
  }

  // recursively scan lists for smallest teams
  for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    int minGroupNumber = skillLevels[i].size();
    list<int>::iterator iterator = skillLevels[i].begin();
    int skillLevel = skillLevels[i].front();
    while (!skillLevels[i].empty()) {
      int currentGroupSize = findGroupsSizes(skillLevel, &iterator, skillLevels[i]); 
      if (currentGroupSize < minGroupNumber)
        minGroupNumber = currentGroupSize;
      skillLevels[i].pop_front();
    }
    cout << minGroupNumber << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I already know that what's causing the error trying to call the "erase" function like this:
    it = list.erase(it);

Which I typed in bold in the code. I don't understand why it's giving me the following output, since from what I understand erase() just needs an iterator to the location of the list to be deleted?:

```
teamFormation.cpp: In function ‘int findHigherSkillLevel(int, std::list<int>::iterator*, std::list<int>&)’:
teamFormation.cpp:13:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::list<int>::erase(std::list<int>::iterator*&)’
     it = *list.erase(it);    
                        ^
teamFormation.cpp:13:24: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/list:64:0,
                 from teamFormation.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/list.tcc:108:5: note: std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<int>]
     list<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/list.tcc:108:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::list<int>::iterator* {aka std::_List_iterator<int>*}’ to ‘std::list<int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/list:63:0,
                 from teamFormation.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1193:7: note: std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<int>]
       erase(iterator __first, iterator __last)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1193:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
teamFormation.cpp: In function ‘int findLowerSkillLevel(int, std::list<int>::iterator*, std::list<int>&)’:
teamFormation.cpp:24:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::list<int>::erase(std::list<int>::iterator*&)’
     it = *list.erase(it);
                        ^
teamFormation.cpp:24:24: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/list:64:0,
                 from teamFormation.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/list.tcc:108:5: note: std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<int>]
     list<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/list.tcc:108:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::list<int>::iterator* {aka std::_List_iterator<int>*}’ to ‘std::list<int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/list:63:0,
                 from teamFormation.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1193:7: note: std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<int>]
       erase(iterator __first, iterator __last)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1193:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
teamFormation.cpp: In function ‘int findGroupsSizes(int, std::list<int>::iterator*, std::list<int>&)’:
teamFormation.cpp:35:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::list<int>::erase(std::list<int>::iterator*&)’
   it = *list.erase(it);
                      ^
teamFormation.cpp:35:22: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/list:64:0,
                 from teamFormation.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/list.tcc:108:5: note: std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<int>]
     list<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/list.tcc:108:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::list<int>::iterator* {aka std::_List_iterator<int>*}’ to ‘std::list<int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/list:63:0,
                 from teamFormation.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1193:7: note: std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<int>]
       erase(iterator __first, iterator __last)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1193:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory: at that point `it` is not a `std::list::iterator`, it's actually an `std::list::iterator*`. You must dereference the pointer (as you did just on the previous line).

Comment: So I have to dereference it appropriately?

Comment: Yes, generally speaking `Type` and `Type*` are different types and you must use them appropriately. In this case you either dereference the pointer or lose the pointer altogether and use a reference.

Comment: Ok it works now, I changes it = list.erase(it) into *it = list.erase(*it) and it's fine. Thank you for your help!